# Viem's PublicClient#watchContractEvent with WSS transport: Socket closed

Tags: events, websocket, viem

New `PublicClient` instances created with WSS transport immediately fail to watch contract events if created after a period of the app inactivity - i.e. if no `PublicClient` was created or used for a few hours. The issue isn't tied to the lifetime of any single instance but seems related to the time elapsed since the last active use across all instances. I tried creating multiple instances to avoid WSS closing due to inactivity.

Here's how I'm setting up the `PublicClient`:

```typescript
createPublicClient({
  chain: arbitrum,
  transport: webSocket(wssEndpoint, {
    key: 'arbitrum',
    name: arbitrum.name,
  }),
})
```

When attempting to use these after a period of inactivity, I receive errors indicating that the WebSocket connection is closed when calling `publicClient.watchContractEvent`:

```
WebSocket request failed.
URL: wss://host.com/provider_secret_key
Request body: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":94,"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[...],"fromBlock":"0xb8ccdf8"}]}
Details: Socket is closed.
Version: viem@2.8.11
```

On the other side Chainstack reports HTTP 499 errors.

This seems not to be related to the number of instances but rather to the duration of inactivity.

Are WSS sockets reused by `createPublicClient`? If so, is there a method to either ensure a fresh connection for each new instance or to keep the existing connections alive?

Is there a way to explicitly close or destroy a `PublicClient` instance to manage these connections better?

https://github.com/wevm/viem/discussions/2011
https://github.com/wevm/viem/discussions/1958